# How to get the previous record id when Ids are not in a sequence order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with id and name. But id is not saving in a sequence order. when I have a specific id at that time I want to get the previous record id.

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | john |
| 15 | wick |
| 18 | suthi |
| 35 | kandu |
| 179 | keerthi |
| 201 | nuwan |

If I have a id as 179. I want to get the previous record id. Please provide me a query for get the pervious column id.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Not with you , whilst the id's in the sample have gaps they are in ascending sequential order

Comment: You need date column as well

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, take a look of `lag` & `lead` commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to get the previous value(if it exists) if you have one :

```
select max(id) from table1 where id < your_current_id_value
```

If your `your_current_id_value` is 179, then you will get 35, but if you have 1, then you will get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < @Your_id LIMIT 1
```

In SQL server:

```
SELECT * FROM table as table1 
INNER JOIN table as table2
on table1.ID = (table2.ID -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data I added some values for test considering Preivous ID is smaller than Current ID

```
create table MYTABLE(
   Id   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,name VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
(Id,name) VALUES 
(1,'john'),
(3,'suthi'), ----test previous record id
(8,'kandu'), ----test previous record id
(15,'wick'),
(17,'keerthi'), ----test previous record id
(18,'suthi'),
(35,'kandu'),
(40,'nuwan'), ----test previous record id
(179,'keerthi'),
(201,'nuwan');
```

your desired query

```
SELECT A.NAME,
       A.CurrentID,
       B.PreviousID
FROM   (SELECT Max(ID) CurrentID,
               NAME
        FROM   MYTABLE
        GROUP  BY NAME) A
       JOIN (SELECT Min(ID) PreviousID,
                    NAME
             FROM   MYTABLE
             GROUP  BY NAME) B
         ON A.NAME = B.NAME
            AND A.CurrentID > B.PreviousID
```

Output

| NAME | CurrentID | PreviousID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kandu | 35 | 8 |
| keerthi | 179 | 17 |
| nuwan | 201 | 40 |
| suthi | 18 | 3 |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=521b39773953fd289138c3ba7ac2df2e)